# jQuery contenteditable selector not working after append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple list of `contenteditable` `divs` and I want to add new `divs` with a button and get the value of the `contentediable` like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add item" />

<div class="itemContainer">
  <div class="item" id="item1" contenteditable="true">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item2" contenteditable="true">
    Item 2
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {

  $("#addItem").click(function() {
    $(".itemContainer").append('<div class="item" id="item3" contenteditable="true">Item 3</div>');
  });

  $("[contenteditable]").blur(function() {
        console.log($(this).html());
  });

});
```

**Fiddle**

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyvgv39h/13/)

The problem is that the `console.log` does not show the value of the `contenteditable div` after I pushed the button `Add Item`

The first 2 items are working properly.

How can I access the `contenteditable` in case of I have appended it to the DOM?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Yes, exactly! I had to add the `$(document).on(` function. http://jsfiddle.net/dyvgv39h/30/

Comment: @rwur  also div append code needs to be correct in a way so that it will not add `Item 3` repeatedly. You can check my answer for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** You need to use [jQuery event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

**2.** Also, you ***need to correct appending div code*** as it always pastes div ***with the repeated text of `Item 3`*** every-time.

```
$(".itemContainer").on('blur',"[contenteditable]",function() {
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(function() {

  $("#addItem").click(function() {
    $(".itemContainer").append(`<div class="item" id="item1" contenteditable="true">
    Item `+($('.item').length+1)+`
  </div>`);
  });

   $(".itemContainer").on('blur',"[contenteditable]",function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add item" />

<div class="itemContainer">
  <div class="item" id="item1" contenteditable="true">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item2" contenteditable="true">
    Item 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script.

```
$(function() {
  $("#addItem").click(function() {
    $(".itemContainer").append('<div class="item" id="item3" contenteditable="true">Item 3</div>');
  });

  $(document).on("blur",".itemContainer [contenteditable]",function() {
        alert($(this).html());
  });

});
```

When you update the DOM dynamically you need to bind the event to newly updated Elements. Which can be done using `$(document).on` function.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/dyvgv39h/27/)